# my underscore template is not working in jade

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to escape <> in javascript underscore template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362290/how-to-escape-in-javascript-underscore-template)

in the view i have a template

```
script(id='productTemplate',type='text/template')
        a(href="/edit?<%= id %>", class='products')
            <img src="<%= photo %>", alt="<%= name %>" />
            p.product_name
                <%= name%>
```

it works well except that anchor  tag's href attribute , it wont render the <%= id %>.

but when i put the <%= id %> next to the <%= name%> it works , and when i put the <%= name%>

in the href="<%= name%>" it again wont render.

please help me.

Comment: yes am using jade on the server side to produce underscore template, do u have any idea why that dosent work when i put the <%=id %> in the anchor href attribute

Comment: right the out put is a mass,<a href="&lt;%= id%&gt;" name="&lt;%=id%&gt;" class="products"> why the "<" is converted to '&lt'

Comment: and do u know how to fix it please help