# how to escape <> in javascript underscore template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, escaping, pug

when using underscore template i want to interpolate a value in anchor's href attribute like

```
a(href= "<%= id %>", class='products') //underscore template in jade
```

but the out put is

```
<a href="&lt;% id %&gt;" class="products">
```

so how to escape the < and > sign , and interpolate the value correctly?

Comment: Did you actually mean to do this : a(href= "<%= id %>", class='products')

Comment: @chenliang, Can you provide more detail?  What you want is not valid HTML.

Comment: here is the same question check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351148/my-underscore-template-is-not-working-in-jade

Comment: @chenliang, Do not post the same question twice.  That is not tolerated here.  Read the FAQ before posting again:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  Please delete one of your questions.

Comment: sorry but the on one answer the first one and i really need this to be solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use != instead of = to unescape.

In your case:

```
a.products(href!="<%= id %>")
```